# Angular :  [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Tags: angularjs

Привет..
Есть ошибка

**[$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations.**

С примера

```
{{ 8897 | myfilter }}

.filter('myfilter', function() {
return function(input) {
// input will be the string we pass in
if (input)
return input+Math.random();
}
})
```

В чем причины появления данной ошибки?

Answer (score 1):

В том, что $digest не может закончить drity-check, вот примерный псевдо-код:

```
$digest {
  do {
     dirty = false;

     EXEC {{ 8897 | myfilter }} => 8897.1951065354514867  
        IF newValue !== oldValue THEN
            dirty = true

  } while (dirty);
}
```